# Move all folders without a specific file

Tags: bash, directory, find

I have a top folder with a lot of subfolders, where I would like to move all folders which do not have the file "banner.jpg" to another place.

I know that I could build a big python script for it for example, but I wonder if there is an easy simple solution with bash and `find`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 final                                              # test material
$ ls                                                                 # check'em
dir1/  dir2/  final/                                                 # it's ok
$ touch dir1/banner.jpg                                              # this 
$ for d in dir* ; do [[ ! -f $d/banner.jpg ]] && mv $d final ; done  # solution
$ ls
dir1/  final/
$ ls final/
dir2/
```

Add quotes around the `"$d"` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(find #dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/banner.jpg" ';' -print) ;do mv $i #newdir;done
```

#dir= replace with base dir or./

#newdir=path to new location

edit1: added '!' after d to include all dir which do not include your file

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)